# Using Reduction of Order With Second Linear DEs?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

If I have the characteristic equation
$$
ar(r-1)+br+c
$$
with a repeated root r1, how can I use the method of reduction of order to show that
$$
y=x^{r1}(c_{1} + c_{2}ln(x))
$$
is the general solution of the DE?

I know that one solution is $$x^{r1}$$

I know how to do this with a numerical example, but when it comes to the parameters a,b & c, I seem to have some difficulty with the proof.

Could someone guide me through this?

Comment: I answered this question yesterday. If you are still unable to proceed consider reading this link or almost any differential equations book. http://www.math.ttu.edu/~drager/Classes/08Summer/M3350/eceqns.pdf

Comment: I apologize for posting this, I didn't feel I was sufficiently clear with my original post.

Comment: @TylerHG - I was confused how the parameter c had disappeared in the example you provided.

Comment: At the beginning I just rewrote the DE by dividing through by $a$. Then renaming the constants $b/a$ and $c/a$ to be $a$ and $b$ respectively. You can do this as they are arbitrary and $a$ is assumed to be nonzero

Comment: OK, that clears up everything now.  I understand you can do that because they are parameters, so it all makes sense.  Thanks!

Comment: They are just constants. Nothing special just a letter meant to represent a random number